# Is there an online Elixir IDE?

Tags: testing, ide, elixir, pastebin

Please is there an online Elixir IDE?

I can only find [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_erlang_online.php) and [ideone](http://ideone.com/) for Erlang.

It would make learning Elixir fun, as we could test scripts and code ideas on the go without a PC.

Like a PasteBin... but for Elixir.

Comment: Just found http://elixirexperience.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just started learning Elixir and have been using Nitrous after stumbling across this: http://blog.nitrous.io/2014/06/03/intro-to-elixir.html. It's referencing the Nitrous.io VM and IDE. They have a free level, which I'm using for now.

The IDE is not Elixir specific but has worked reasonably well so far. I can start in terminal mode when I'm playing with examples in iex or go to a full IDE when I'm writing code that needs more than an interactive mode. It's a bit behind, supporting 1.0.2 as the current version and there's no "real" Elixir support like there is for first class languages, but I've been able to use it from within a browser with no problems for the stuff I've been playing with.

*EDIT: As of Apr 23 2015, just a few days after this response, Nitrous has effectively killed off their free tier and bumped the prices on their other tiers. No longer viable for just learning Elixir (unless you've got excess cash, that is). Too bad.*

Comment: I was hoping for a tool like Postbin

Comment: or possibly any other FREE online REPL for Elixir. there are a few online for Erlang

Comment: http://elixirexperience.com/ is basically a tutorial, but not a bad effort

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a great online REPL for elixir: http://play.elixirbyexample.com/

Comment: play.elixirbyexample.com has been down for a while, but I wish it came back, because it was nice, and because of dangling dead links to some (lost?) code.

Answer (score 0):

Atom editor have a cool package called Language Elixir.